# Fundamental JSON-like object structure?

Tags: javascript, python, json, schema

How to store data correctly in a JSON-like object? From what I've seen, there are two ways to store data inside a json object. Both have different ways to access the data (examples in Python):

Option 1:

```
obj1 = [
    {"id": 1, "payload": "a"},
    {"id": 2, "payload": "b"},
    {"id": 3, "payload": "c"},
]
```

Access a certain id's payload in option 1:

```
for element in obj1:
    if element["id"] == 2:
        print(element["payload"])
```

This means, the whole list of elements has to be scanned (possibly) to find the right id and return its value.

On the other hand theres Option 2:

```
obj2 = {
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c",
}
```

To access the payload of the second "id" is just:

```
print(obj2[2])
```

My question now is, why is it more common to see option 1, even though that one seems more complicated to search through? When would I use option 1 and when option 2?

Comment: Depends on use case...

Comment: Well, you've got an array of objects vs a single object - so its up to you to decide which is correct for the task. In terms of expansion and legibility, I would argue that the first option is better. Want to add a new property? You can't do that with option two. Plus, you could always just use a single array for option 2, it doesn't necessarily need to be an object.

Comment: There's also option 3 which is an object of objects

Answer (score 2):

We should clarify some terminology.

When you put a list of values in `[]`, you are creating an array; it is keyed by the array index, not by any element of the data.

When you put a list of keys and values in `{}`, you are creating an object; you can, as you note, locate a value if you know the corresponding key.

There are *many* differences between the two structures.  In the particular use case you site - wanting to find a data instance based on one of its field's values - an object that uses that field as the key makes sense.

But object keys are unordered.  And arrays lend themselves more naturally to having you iterate over all their elements.

It depends what you're going to do with the values; that's why there isn't just one data structure.

Comment: Okay, then let's say instead of the array, I have the object `obj1 = {"data": [] }`. Now I have two objects. I see that type of object rather often as responses from webservices. I guess my question is mostly directed towards IDs. Why aren't IDs always stored as option2 ?

Comment: I don't see what it has to do with anything, whether you wrap the array inside of an object.  The reason people sometimes use arrays instead of objects is they sometimes need data structures that have the characteristics of arrays rather than objects.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from technical artifacts that somehow evolved, option one makes sense in case the order of elements is important.